# Run scala script save in utf-8 gets error

Tags: windows, scala, utf-8

I am new to scala and I tried some small programs in book "Programming in Scala", when the scala script is saved in ANSI, it works well. But when I saved it in UTF-8, a error was thrown up as "error: illegal character ?import". I run this small example program on windows.  And the example program is like

```
import scala.io.Source
if(args.isEmpty){

}else{
    Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines.toList.zipWithIndex.foreach { case (line, i) => println(i + "    "+line)}
}
```

what's going on there?

Comment: You did not ask how to correct it, but you can specify the encoding explicitly, like this: `scalac -encoding utf8 ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you saved your file with [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

If you save your source code without BOM (How to do it depends on which text editor you are using), it will works fine.